# How to keep speed after collision in Matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

When I use Matter.js to test something, a box(rect) is slowing down after a collision, even I set up the `friction` and `frictionAir` to 0.

```
var options = {
  friction:0,
  frictionAir:0,
  restitution: 1,
}
```

Also, I don't want the gravity.

```
world.gravity.y = 0;
```

Comment: that seems like an unfixed problem. https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/256