# How to make objects without loss of speed using phaser js matter?

Tags: javascript, matter.js, phaserjs

Example, removed gravity, removed friction, made maximum elasticity. The balls still stop. What else can you do to make the balls move endlessly? Or is this a phaser js bug?

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true,
            gravity: { y: 0 } // Отключаем гравитацию для этой сцены
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

function preload() {
    // Здесь можно загрузить изображения, если нужно использовать вместо примитивных фигур
}

function create() {
    //this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);

    let width = this.game.config.width;
    let height = this.game.config.height;

    // Параметры для стенок
    let wallOptions = {
        isStatic: true,
        restitution: 1,
        friction: 0,
        frictionAir: 0,

    };

    // Верхняя стенка
    this.matter.add.rectangle(width / 2, 0, width, 10, wallOptions);
    // Нижняя стенка
    this.matter.add.rectangle(width / 2, height, width, 10, wallOptions);
    // Левая стенка
    this.matter.add.rectangle(0, height / 2, 10, height, wallOptions);
    // Правая стенка
    this.matter.add.rectangle(width, height / 2, 10, height, wallOptions);


    // Создание 10 круглых объектов
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Создаем круглый объект с радиусом 15
        let circle = this.matter.add.circle(Phaser.Math.Between(100, 700), Phaser.Math.Between(100, 500), 15, {
            restitution: 1, // Полная упругость для отскока без потерь
            friction: 0, // Уменьшение трения для минимизации потерь скорости
            frictionAir: 0,
            render: {
                fillStyle: '#ff0000' // Задаем красный цвет заливки
            }
        });

        // Задаем объекту случайный импульс
        this.matter.body.applyForce(circle, { x: circle.position.x, y: circle.position.y }, {
            x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.05,
            y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.05
        });
    }

    // Создание 10 статичных квадратных объектов
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Создаем статичный квадратный объект со стороной 50
        this.matter.add.rectangle(Phaser.Math.Between(100, 700), Phaser.Math.Between(100, 500), 50, 50, {
            isStatic: true,
            restitution: 1, // Полная упругость
            friction: 0, // Уменьшение трения
            render: {
                fillStyle: '#ff0000' // Задаем красный цвет заливки
            }
        });
    }
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

[https://codepen.io/attfcwtz-the-encoder/pen/QWoovQq][1]

I didn’t figure out how to add links to codepen here, the validator just missed it.
[1]: https://codepen.io/attfcwtz-the-encoder/pen/QWoovQq

Comment: _**fyi:**_ you cannot post only post links to a codepen, you need to add some code, or use stackoverflow embedded codeditor.

Comment: I don't think this is a Phaser issue/bug, this is definitely a matter.js Bug, it is mentioned in this older post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977240/how-to-keep-speed-after-collision-in-matter-js . I added the tag: **matter.js**, like this more people with matter.js knowhow will see it. They might have a solution.